# Access USB Pendrive files in my android app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-developer-api, radfileexplorer

How can I access files on usb drive from my android app. Device is not rooted. I do not want to use storage access framework. Is it possible to get file path using android USB Host apis. 
In nexus devices and many other vendors', usb storage is not a mounted storage so it cannot be accessed normally.

Comment: The requirements and limitations of this have been covered numerous times before

Comment: Use the storage access framework on APIs > 19. For APIs < see older questions already asked here.  USB Host Apis wont save you.

Comment: @Chris: Can you share me a link where there is a correct answer for this. I am not able to find any workable answer.

Comment: @petey: thanks for your comment. Actually I do not want to use SAF because of some functionalities of my app will get affected. I need some other solution. I can see ES File explorer can list files from usb storage, and they do not use SAF. I am wondering what apis have they used.

Comment: Done.  Keep in mind that stackoverflow is for specific questions.  *It is explicitly not to be used to ask for code to use for a project*, and accessing a mass storage device via the host apis will require *a lot* of of code within your app.

Comment: @Chris: some confusions if you can clarify. When otg pen drive attached I saw LG mobiles are showing contents as normal sd card, in their gallary and other app. Few other mobiles detect it as external storage when but not showing contents in gallery. And all others are not detecting as external storage also. Can you please explain this.

Comment: As explained at the link "Android" did not support this, but presumably despite that a given device manufacturer could add non-standard capabilities to a specific device.

Answer (score 0):

If the Android device supports [USB Host](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html) mode, you need to have a [USB OTG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go) cable to connect to the flash drive. This cable has a resistor in line that signals to the USB controller on the Android device to switch to Host Mode.

These cables can be purchased from many online retailers.

Short answer is: No, your app alone cannot access the USB device.

Comment: Yes I am using USB OTG pendrive only. ES File explorer is able to detect my pendrive. So my app should also be able to read and list files, though I am not able to find how to make it work.

Comment: @PraveenPandey The first link in my answer regarding USB Host goes to the Android API for handling USB Host mode. It might have the info you need.

Comment: Justin, I have gone through this. But here there isn't any information about how to list files.

Comment: Indeed, the host APIs have no knowledge of mass storage protocol or filesystems.